# Frame 6:8 - Why do we not get stuck in the recursion?

Tags: scheme, reasoned-schemer

We get:

```lisp
(defrel (alwayso)
  (conde
    (#s)
    ((alwayso))))

(run 1 q
  (alwayso)
  #u)
```

The book (2nd ed) says:

> *"`alwayso` succeeds, followed by `#u`, which causes `(alwayso)` to be retried, which succeeds again".*

I still don't get the control flow. Why aren't both arms of the `conde` tried (continuing in the recursion) before stepping out to `#u`?

Comment: Please include relevant definitions from the book. Not everyone has memorized it and knows which `conde` you're talking about.

Comment: Added `alwayso`

Comment: @amalloy 2ed of the book is supposed to have the interleaving `conde`, but it doesn't matter, because the first disjunct is a singleton stream.

Comment: (I've rechecked the 2ed book code by now, evidently, and it is indeed interleaving).

Answer (score 2):

> "Why aren't both arms of the `conde` tried (continuing in the recursion) before stepping out to `#u`?"

You meant, why the *second* arm is not tried before stepping out to `#u` with the result from the first.

The short answer is, [lazy-sequences](/questions/tagged/lazy-sequences) (also, [lazy-evaluation](/questions/tagged/lazy-evaluation)) paradigm.

Under the eager evaluation paradigm, each goal produces all if its solutions in full. If their number is unbounded ("infinite"), this means infinite looping, indeed as you expected.

Under the lazy evaluation paradigm, each goal produces its solutions one by one -- meaning, it produces only its first result and stays ready to produce the next when and if requested.

---

Goals produce their resulting substitutions one by one, as if by `yield` in Python. So do the combined goals as well. The `conde` combination combines its subgoal in a certain way (see below), and produces the combined goal's results one by one. Thus

```
#| (defrel (alwayso)
  (conde
    (#s)
    ((alwayso)))) |#

(run 1 q
  (alwayso)
  #u)
=
(run 1 q
  (conde
    (#s)          ; 1.1
    ((alwayso)))  ; 1.2  ->  ; 1  
  #u)                        ; 2
```

`run`'s first goal, the combined goal `conde`, produces its results one by one, each result being fed to the second `run` goal, `#u`, *as soon as it is produced*.

If all the solutions of `run`'s first subgoal were to be produced before feeding the list of results to the next subgoal, the evaluation would never end for any goal capable of producing infinite list (or more precisely, unbounded stream) of results.

These streams are thus *lazy* streams, and lists are *eager* lists. The difference is operational. Under eager scheme, the first subgoal's list is first built in full, and only then processed by the next goal. When the number of results is infinite, building an infinite eager list will take infinite time.

Thus under the eager evaluation paradigm it would indeed get stuck in the recursion inside that `conde`.

Under the lazy evaluation paradigm, chosen by the book's implementation, it gets stuck in a bigger loop, bouncing off the `#u` back every time. But the `conde` works, producing its resulting substitutions successfully one by one.

Scheme itself is an eager language. Delaying the production of the rest of stream is achieved by putting it behind the lambda, Roughly,

```
(cons   1       rest-of-list)
```

(an eager list) is replaced with

```
(cons   1  (^() code-to-produce-the-rest-of-stream))
```

(a lazy stream).

---

`alwayso` is defined so that it produces an infinite stream of copies of its input substitution, unchanged. But it produces them one by one.

Then `run` feeds this stream from its first goal, to the second goal, `#u`, which rejects it. Since `run 1` demands one solution from its subgoals, it retries them until one solution / substitution goes through.

Which never happens.

So this should result in infinite looping.

Again, both arms *are* tried -- first, the first one; then, after its (one) result gets rejected by the subsequent `#u`, the second arm is tried. And the resulting substitution gets rejected, again. Ad infinitum:

```
;; we have
(defrel (alwayso)
  (conde
    (#s)
    ((alwayso))))

;; running:
(run 1 q
  (alwayso)
  #u)
=
(run 1 q
  (conde         ; (a OR b) , c
    (#s)
    ((alwayso)))
  #u)
=
(run 1 q         ; (a , c) OR (b , c)
  (conde
    (#s #u)
    ((alwayso) #u)))
=
(run 1 q 
  (alwayso) 
  #u)
=
.....
```

Getting stuck.

---

Following the implementation's definitions closer,

```
(defrel (alwayso)
  (conde
    (#s)
    ((alwayso))))
= ; by def of defrel; with ^ for lambda
(define (alwayso)
  (^s (^() ( (conde
               (#s)                 ; first 
               ((alwayso))) s))))   ; second
= ; by defs of conde, conj and disj
(define (alwayso)
  (^s (^() ( (disj2
                #s                  ; first
                (alwayso) ) s))))   ; second
= ; by def of disj2
(define (alwayso)           ; (-1-)
  (^s (^() (append-inf
               (#s s)               ; first
               ((alwayso) s)) )))   ; second
= ; by defs of #s and alwayso (-1-)
(define (alwayso)
  (^s (^() (append-inf
               (list s)             ; first
               (^() (append-inf     ; second
                      (#s s)
                      ((alwayso) s)) )) )))
= ; by def of append-inf
(define (alwayso)
  (^s (^() (cons s                  ; first
               (^() (append-inf     ; second
                      (#s s)
                      ((alwayso) s)) )) )))
= ; by def of append-inf
(define (alwayso)
  (^s (^() (cons s
               (^() (cons s
                      ((alwayso) s)) )) )))
=
  ....
```

so indeed we see here a definition which produces a stream of an unbounded number of copies of the input substitution `s`, as and when requested, as the result of a call `((alwayso) <s>)`.

Or, in pseudocode, writing `++` for `append-inf` and `[s]` for `(list s)`,

```
((alwayso) s) 
= 
  ((#s OR (alwayso)) s)
=
  (#s s) ++ ((alwayso) s)
=
  [s] ++ ((#s OR (alwayso)) s)
=
  [s] ++ [s] ++ ((#s OR (alwayso)) s)
=
  [s] ++ [s] ++ [s] ++ ((#s OR (alwayso)) s)
=
  [s      s      s      .... ]
```

Finally,

```
(run 1 q (alwayso) #u)
= ; by def of run
  (let ((q (var 'q)))
    (map (reify q)
         (run-goal 1 (conj (alwayso) #u))))
= ; by defs of run-goal and conj
  (let ((q (var 'q)))
    (map (reify q)
         (take-inf 1 ((conj2 (alwayso) #u) empty-s))))
= ; by defs of conj2 and #u
  (let ((q (var 'q)))
    (map (reify q)
         (take-inf 1 
           (append-map-inf (^s '())
               ((alwayso) empty-s)))))
```

and no matter how many `empty-s`'s it applies the `(^s '())` to, to append the results together, all the results are empty lists, so it can't `take` even one of the contained results because there are none. In *pseudocode*, writing `s0` for `empty-s`,

```
  (take-inf 1 
              (append-map-inf (^s '())
                     ((alwayso) empty-s)))
= ; as established above
  (take-inf 1 (append-map-inf (^s [])
                          [ s0 s0 s0 .... ]))
= ; by def of append-map-inf
  (take-inf 1 
    (append-inf ((^s []) s0)
              (append-map-inf (^s [])
                             [ s0 s0 .... ])))
= ; by beta-reduction
  (take-inf 1 
    (append-inf []
              (append-map-inf (^s [])
                             [ s0 s0 .... ])))
= ; be def of append-if
  (take-inf 1 
              (append-map-inf (^s [])
                             [ s0 s0 .... ]))
= ; and we're back where we've started
  <LOOPING>
```

Or, symbolically,

```
  (take 1 (append-map-inf (^s [])
                      [ s0 s0 s0 .... ]))
=
  (take 1 (append-inf [ [] [] [] .... ]))
=
  (take 1 [             ; sic!
```

So it gets stuck.

Comment: I think I finally understood what you were asking. (It's hard to guess all by myself.) I've edited the answer.

Comment: I think the bit I was missing is that the run call takes the result of the first arm and feeds it to the second one. If you don't know that bit, the entire thing does not make any sense.

Comment: yes, run has an implicit conj.

Comment: I mean I had to look up the definitions in the book, and then I followed them as noted in the answer. I found them through the book's index. `run` is defined so that it makes a reporting `var`, then maps `reify` onto result of `run-goal` of all the goals in `run` put into a `conj`.